# How to conditionally expand element according to height of its content in ionic?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to expand my element conditionally, so that on click it will expand according to height of its content.

Component's html:

```
<div class="container"  [style.height]="enlarged === true ? '120px' : '50px'">
  <div class="textContainer">
    <ion-label>
      Welcome    </ion-label>
   <ion-label>{{ content}}</ion-label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using **auto**. Such as:

```
 [style.height]="enlarged === true ? 'auto' : '50px'"
```